# Is there something about 是在 that is meaningful in 让任意的值是在一个上下文当中?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I was reading [this article](http://jiyinyiyong.github.io/monads-in-pictures/) when I came across this:

> **让任意的值是在一个上下文当中**. 现在的情况你可以想象一个可以把值放进去的盒子

Because of the [English version](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html), I know that this is saying:

> Let an arbitrary value be in a context. You can think of this as a box that you can put the value in.

However, I've never seen 是 and 在 together like this with 让 earlier in then sentence. I thought that 在 by itself would have been fine. Is there something about 是在 that is meaningful in this sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The article in the first link is clearly machine-translated from the original version in the second link with some partials not even translated. A lot of the sentences are difficult to understand, if they make any sense at all. 让任意的值是在一个上下文当中 is just wrong in Chinese. One proper translation might be 把任意值放到上下文当中.